# dynamic expansion BorderPanel (Center element)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to place the FXML file (AnchorPane) in the center of the FXML file (BorderPane) and it works, but it does not stretch along the program boundary, but has its standard dimensions, how can I fix this?

Thank.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    public void initMenuBar() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("../view/fxml/menu.fxml"));
            rootLayout = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initMainWindow() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("../view/fxml/mainWindow.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = loader.load();

            rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);

            MainWindowController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMain(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

        initMenuBar();

        initMainWindow();
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

FXML menu - here I am writing menuBar:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="325.0" prefWidth="750.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="model.MainWindowController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ccccff;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

FXML mainWindow - here I am writing the main program

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="mainWindowPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="750.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ccccff;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="model.MainWindowController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane fx:id="mainWindowPane2" dividerPositions="0.7591973244147158" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="451.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Сайт" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Почта" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Логин" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Пароль" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="5.0" layoutY="6.0" text="Дополнительная информация" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="6.0" />
                  <Label layoutX="5.0" layoutY="33.0" text="Label" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: @charlesLgn yes i added

Comment: I thought that he would not be needed

Comment: Could you provide full fxml - with imports? It's always nice to nice and not force people to add imports on their own.

Comment: @PrzemekKrysztofiak updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do that ?

[image: the result]

in mainMzenu.fxml you have :

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="mainWindowPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="750.0" ...
```

what does it mean ?

`minHeight="-Infinity"` mean `minHeight=prefHeight`

so you bloc the minimum and there is no problem with that. the problem is that you also bloc the wax with `maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"` so what you need to do is to change this value.

```
maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
```

> if you use scene builder you can pick up `MAX_VAL`

the result :

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="mainWindowPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="750.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ccccff;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="model.MainWindowController">
  <children>
       .....
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

you can also remove the value :

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="mainWindowPane" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="750.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ccccff;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="model.MainWindowController">
  <children>
       .....
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```